# Add Dynamic Behavior on Component in QML

Tags: qml, qt5, behavior

Recently I wanna add behavior in js function in QML but I dont know how!
For example , how I can do this:

```
    Behavior on color{ 
        id:behavior
        enabled:false;
        ColorAnimation {}
    }
```

```
    Rectangle{
        id:rect 
        Component.onCompleted: rect.setBehavior = behavior; // it's wrong expression 
    }
```

I just need some API like top wrong expression , is that exist?

<strike>also I tried bottom code too but couldn't work:</strike>

also I can try below code too :

```
   Component.onCompleted: behavior.enabled = true;
```

<strike>because I want prevent working behavior when creating rectangle and enable it after completed  , but it won't work correctly!</strike>

but when I have a lot of behaviors on specific conditions I just want use one line code for change behavior on (for example) Color , something like:
`Component.setNewBehaviorOnColor(specificBehaviorOnColorID);`

Comment: You might be able to attach a behavior dynamically but I've never seen it done before. It is usually done declaratively in QML - I think using `enabled` is your best bet. If you post code we can run that shows why onCompleted isn't working we can help you with that.

Comment: @DavidK.Hess Thx for helping <3 , I understood my design was incorrect cause of that enabled and disabled couldn't work.
but now I really want learn how I can assign new behavior in specific conditions!it might be good for future. if I find solution I will share that here.

Comment: I don't think you can imperatively change the `Behavior` of a property from JavaScript. `Behavior` elements are rather special in QML. Could you explain the initial problem you are trying to solve this way?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using `Instantiator` + `PropertyAnimation` instead of `Behavior`.

By doing it this way, your Javascript code will merely just set the `Instantiator` `model`. That way, you can start/stop any animation you wish by setting or clearing the `model` property:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    id: page

    title: "Instantiator + PropertyAnimation"

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        x: 100; y: 100; width: 100; height: 100
        color: "red"
    }
    
    Instantiator {
        id: instantiator
        model: 0
        PropertyAnimation {
            target: rect
            property: modelData[0]
            to: modelData[1]
            duration: 500
            Component.onCompleted: start()
        }
    }
    
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            instantiator.model = [
                ["x",Math.random()*page.width],
                ["y",Math.random()*page.height],
                ["width",Math.random()*200],
                ["height",Math.random()*200],
                ["color",Qt.rgba(
                    Math.random(),
                    Math.random(),
                    Math.random(),
                    1)]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAADy3icrVKxTsMwEN3zFVamFiIrRWIJYqjKwlCpZa06mMQkFo4vulxFK9R/x3HaYDcZGLjB9vnePfvdnaobQGJb2h5U/hmpwOUrMISg22gjSsm+I2ZNFRlrrBs5jxRpmbH41bQkDClBgOyebRAaiXRaGlULUmDiHv4mcwsr9ZXsSoj2frg4ZmyRpk/sdNm/VEHV5VxJVVbknAGfgwa0f0BZxO7y7Fa3BP8K31ReaAjUUEidsV/ykRKPxRVAYCnpRkFnzSUx6zlfBIldug9zwQ8uwmBxQPdexh49rZ2twHbJSEMcTHfWkqTVY9UgzeYD9HxbizUcWrlEKTwJwuQVYMs/lNZdX9HSDkFLr+0YdOShaL903Clgz2wXQDrbxcc4WQuqOApTQD2b33WTw11D98kE/jSJ75s+meCobpMe0nQS3PP8Fe3GKk62xLF8F7MRwpXUZxqT/B9kMQ+nYz9q8/kHCwn2PQ==)